# How to make fixed positioned element scroll when it overflows the y body axis?

Tags: css, css-position, overflow

How to make fixed positioned element scroll when it overflows the document ?

On my site https://mkdrzwi.pl/ when I open 'BEZPŁATNY POMIAR' button on the right side when it overflows the **y body axis** it won't scroll, I have tried to fix this but to no avail, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add height for content div:

```
.October2018_formwrap__inner {
   height: 555px;
}
```

Comment: Try to minimalize height to extreme and see it does not work, I mean, there indeed is scroll, but it does not scroll so that send button is visible when you minimalize height of the vieweport below 600px

Comment: U can add ..October2018_formwrap__inner {max-height: 85vh;}